# TortoiseHG merging local into branch head

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have a repo in TortoiseHG with a single branch (next version development), but modifications to the local (bug fixes)... something like...

```
Local 0-------3--4
       \
Branch  1--2
```

I want to do some more development on the branch version but with the subsequent Local changes merged into it.  And I want to leave the local version in a state where I can continue development without the branch changed.

I'm not sure if what I'm asking is actually possible, or whether coming from a Visual SourceSafe environment is just clouding my ability to see something that should be obvious.

In fact, thinking about it a bit more (as I was writing the above) I'm wondering if my approach is the wrong way around.  I should probably have continued with the future development in the local version and then create a bug-fix branch that I could have merged back into local one.

So the question is, is there a way to get around what I want to do with the current repo setup, or should I export the individual revisions and rebuild the repo from scratch?  (Or any other options?)

Comment: What is Local and Branch in terms of **Mercurial**? It's obviously unclean to me. Just show `hg glog`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've never used Mercurial directly (always used TortoiseHG, never done any command-line) so I cannot say for sure.  By "local" I'm referring the original time-line of commitments... however, with my lack of experience with Mercurial/TortoiseHG, I could be talking rubbish

Comment: Not rubbish, but not in correct technical term. Which I want to fix for understanding *problem*. Open THG explorer, select your project in repository registry, RClick on it - Terminal. `hg glog` or `hg log` if 1-st doesn't work

Comment: I think my main terminology mistake was to call it "local" when it's actual name in the repo is "default".  Thanks for your help all the same

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This seems like pretty normal Mercurial handling to me.

You have:

1. Two branches
2. Want to make sure one of the two branches have all the updates of the other
3. Want to make sure that other branch does not have any of the updates from the first (yet)

You basically just have to merge the `Local` branch into the `Branch` branch at regular intervals, but not the other way around.

Whenever you merge to a branch, you first update to the head of that branch. This makes the changeset you commit to persist that merge *be* on that branch as well.

In other words, you would do this:

1. Update to the head of `Branch`
2. Right-click on the head of `Local` and select "Merge with local..." and go through with the merge
3. Commit, this new changeset ends up being *on* the `Branch` branch

The `Local` branch is still blissfully unaware of the changes on the `Branch` branch.

Comment: Thanks for the great response Lasse, and I agree it is Mercurial 101.  It's just that for somebody used to Visual SourceSafe for the last 12 years, even Mercurial 101 is pretty mind-blowing.  Your answer is spot-on, and after playing around with a clone I can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: The best tip I can give regarding Mercurial is that if you're unsure if what you're about to do will have the intended effect, make a complete copy of your working folder, including the .hg folder and everything. Then, experiment, go wild.